# Is there a standard name for the groupby/apply operation?

Tags: pandas, parallel-processing, apply, data-wrangling, custom-function

## Data

CategoricalVariable CV1 : X1,X2,X3...Xn

NumericalVariable   NV1 : 1-1000

Time                    : 0-100

| C1 | Time | NV1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X1 | 0 | 1 |
| X1 | 1 | 100 |
| X2 | 0 | 200 |
| X2 | 1 | 500 |

## Operation 1: Split by Categorical Variable

### DataFrame1

| C1 | Time | NV1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X1 | 0 | 1 |
| X1 | 1 | 100 |

### DataFrame2

| C1 | Time | NV1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X2 | 0 | 200 |
| X2 | 1 | 500 |

## Operation 2: Apply Custom Function

```
import numpy as np 

def custom_func (anyarray):
    last_element_in_array = anyarray [-1] 
    first_element_in_array = anyarray [0] 
    return  np.sin (last_element_in_array) * np.ln (first_element_in_array)
     
custom_func (DataFrame1 ['NV1'].values) # np.sin (100) * np.ln (1)
```

## Operation 3: Re-Combine DataFrame1 and DataFrame2

| C1 | NV1 |
| --- | --- |
| X2 | Custom Function output : np.sin (100) * np.ln (1) |
| X2 | Custom Function output : np.sin (500) * np.ln (200) |

Comment: "Split-apply-combine" https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html

Comment: @PaulH thank you so much. that's the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) operation:

```
data.groupby('C1')['NV1'].apply(custom_func)
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Moreover, does the mix of applying a "custom function" with a "groupby operation" have a name of its own?! given that its one of the most common cases in the history of data transformation I think. To add context, I want to google the fastest way to do that. Especially that now there is vaex,Dask,numba,Spark and all of these speed-boosting packages in python.